# Creating a diagonal matrix with restrictions

Tags: r

```
0 1 3 5 7
1 0 3 5 7
1 3 0 5 7
1 3 5 0 7
1 3 5 7 0
```

I have to generate the matrix above, but I have some restrictions.
I am not allowed to use any built-in functions such as matrix(), cbind(), rbind() (except length()) or any loop. I have to use the apply function for this problem.

The function has only one parameter (let's say 7) to generate this matrix above.

My approach to this problem is, that I create a starting vector and then convert this starting vector to a matrix by using the sapply function. Afterwards, I want to operate on that matrix to get the required output.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: If you have a question, simply ask. Don't put I have a question as your title. This is a question and answer site. Please edit your question with a more informative title,sample data, code, current and expected output.

Comment: Hi @joshuacos2777! Welcome to SO. Get in mind to get answers it´s important to provide data and your last tries (code) in order to solve the problem. It helps us to understand the issue and find solutions faster. Please edit your question with more data

Answer (score 0):

You correctly identified that you can use `sapply` to solve the problem. Please see the code below (quick & dirty):

```
n <- 7

gen_xs <- function(x) c(0, seq(1, x, 2))

move0 <- function(x, pos) {
  if (pos == 0)
    return(x)
  if (pos == length(x) - 1)
    return (c(x[-1], 0))
  xt <- x[x != 0]
  c(xt[1:pos], 0, xt[(pos + 1):length(xt)] )
}

t(sapply(0:((n + 1) / 2), function(x) move0(gen_xs(n), x)))
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    3    5    7
[2,]    1    0    3    5    7
[3,]    1    3    0    5    7
[4,]    1    3    5    0    7
[5,]    1    3    5    7    0
```